# Border collision detection

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm making a game with Sprite Kit and I have the collision detection setup like this:

```
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
    borderBody.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = borderCategory
```

And the handler `-didBeginContact()`:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == borderCategory {
        print("You Lose!")
    }

}
```

I also have this line  to set the contact delegate:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

But when I run the game, the collision is not detected and nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: you need to define contactbitmasks, you can search on here for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/contactTestBitMask). You need to set the `contactTestBitMask` if you want to receive contact/intersection notifications. Unlike `collisionBitMask` whose default value is `0xFFFFFFFF`, the default value for `contactTestBitMask` is `0x00000000`.